# What is the best way to replace NaN values for ranked columns

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

I have a column named `BsmntQual` that gives a ranking on the height of the basement per each house.  These are all of the unique values in this column:

```
print(train['BsmtQual'].unique().tolist())

>>> ['Gd', 'TA', 'Ex', nan, 'Fa']
```

This is the legend of this particular column:

```
BsmtQual: Evaluates the height of the basement

       Ex   Excellent (100+ inches) 
       Gd   Good (90-99 inches)
       TA   Typical (80-89 inches)
       Fa   Fair (70-79 inches)
       Po   Poor (<70 inches
       NA   No Basement < Not to be confused with the nan value above
```

This is what I did for my other ranked columns but this one did not have NaN values:

```
train['ExterQual'] = train['ExterQual'].replace(['Ex', 'Gd', 'TA', 'Fa'], [4, 3, 2, 1])  # Exterior Quality
```

For numerical values, a common way is to fill all NaN values with the mean of the column.  But what is a good way of replacing the NaN values for columns such as these?

[Here](https://github.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/blob/master/train.csv) is the full dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your legend clearly states that missing values mean that there is no basement. You could fill the missing values with ’NoBase’ to make that point clearer (`train[‘BsmtQual’].fillna(‘NoBase’, inplace=True)`). 
When you rank them then, you just add another ranking for ‘NoBase’, maybe 0, based on your example rating that gives a higher value to more quality.

Comment: Read it again.  The legend clearly states that NA = No Basement.  If you look above that, I got a NaN value.  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos If they’re not the same thing, then I’d suggest asking whoever gave you the dataset to make it clear what the missing values represent.

Comment: Okay fine but it's pretty clear mate.  NA & nan don't look that similar.  Anyways.  Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos - when you use pd.read_csv the default parser automatically transforms the string 'NA' into nan values so this answer is correct.  -  there are no 'NA' values in your print..

Comment: @yoav_aaa Good catch. Andros, if you want to ignore that behavior, you can set `keep_default_na = False` to keep pandas from reading `NA` as `nan`, and it will just leave those values as the string `'NA'`.

Answer (score -1):

*method : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None
Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap*

from pandas fillna, these methods can be used or fill in with the highest frequency category.